# Evaluate the following infinite series or state that the series diverges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

From my textbook.

$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-\frac{1}{5})^k$$

My work:

So a constant greater than or equal to $1$ raised to ∞ is ∞.

A number $n$ for $0<n<1$ is $0$. So when taking the limit of this series you get 0 but when formatting the problem a different way $(-1)^k/(5^k)$ it seems like an alternating series. Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: Are you familiar with geometric series? You may know that the sum of the terms up to the term $(-1/5)^{n-1}$ is $\frac{1-(-1/5)^{n}}{1-(-1/5)}$.

Comment: By taking limits as $n \to \infty$ you're looking at the convergence (or divergence) of the sequence, not the series.

Comment: I do not know that definition of the geometric series but I am supposed to solve this by taking the limit but what would the limit converge or diverge to then.

Answer (score 0):

For $-1 <x< 1$, we know $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i=\frac{1}{1-x}$

So in your problem, x = -1/5, sum is 5/6

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve this by using the geometric series test, where |r|< 1, the series converges, and if |r|> 1, it diverges. Since r= -1/5, and you take the absolute value to get 1/5, the series converges because 1/5 < 1.

Comment: Good, but: (1) learn to use mathjax, and (2) the original poster seems to be pretty ignorant or  un-handy with algebra, so another line or two of explanation might be appropriate.